# Error en visual studio al compilar

Tags: visual-studio

Al compilar mi proyecto en VS me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Alguien sabe a que se debe?

por mas que busco no encuentro una solución, ya reinstale el VS y continua el problema.

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

De acuerdo a [esta pregunta](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42867434/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-system-valuetuple), es posible que el lío se deba a un problema de dependencias en tu proyecto (que, asumimos, es .NET aunque no das ninguna pista...)

Puedes:

- Ajustar en el web.config del proyecto, añadiendo ésto:

```
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.3.0" newVersion="4.0.3.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

- Registrar (o revisar que esté registrado) el paquete System.ValueTuple en el machine.config de tu máquina si no quieres cambiar la versión de .NET.

```
<runtime>
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.ValueTuple" publicKeyToken="cc7b13ffcd2ddd51" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-99.99.99.99" newVersion="4.0.1.0" />
    <codeBase version="4.0.1.0" href="e:\exec\System.ValueTuple.dll" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  ...
</assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
```

A partir de .NET 4.7 este paquete fue añadido al core, así que por eso la siguiente opción funciona -->

- Instalar un runtime más reciente (hay gente que con >=4.7.2 le funciona)
- Hacer downgrade del paquete NuGet System.ValueTuple a 4.3.0